# Cookies not showing up when sending request to http://natas18.natas.labs.overthewire.org with pre-existing cookies of the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I get the cookies when I do this:

```
import requests
username="natas18"

password="..."

s=requests.session()

r=s.post("http://natas18.natas.labs.overthewire.org/",auth=(username,password),data={"username":"admin","password":"admin"})

print(r.cookies)
```

---

but when I try to set a cookie (as below) with existing name it gives me a blank list.

### Trying to set cookies

```
import requests

username="natas18"

password="..."

s=requests.session()

r=s.post("http://natas18.natas.labs.overthewire.org/",auth=(username,password),cookies={"PHPSESSID":"10"},data={"username":"admin","password":"admin"})

print(r.cookies)
```

It's giving me a blank cookies list.

Comment: Cookies are not sent in response, unless a Set-Cookie header was set in server. The first time, you tried logging in, and server responded with a cookie. 2nd time, you set the cookie in header, so you are already authenticated, a response for that might not contain the cookie.

Comment: @Kris can you please describe more.I try get request without data but the result was same.